# PaperclipError in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I am getting Paperclip error in my rails application for Windows10. 
**Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError**

I tried every possible thing for  my error. I changed path.`Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "C:/ImageMagick-6.8.5-10/Magick++/bin"`
I tried giving paths like `C:/ImageMagick-6.8.5-10` or `C:/Win/System32`

I tried several commands like `identify` and `convert` but i am unable to solve this error. 
Can you please give a definite solution to solve this error for "Windows 10".

Comment: is there any style for the attachment defined in the model ?

Comment: @GaneshNavale it is not a duplicate que. I have this issue in windows10. the one you referred is for mac

Comment: @SikandarTariq no nothing defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I am concerned, I placed the GnuWin32 directory and all its content somewhere I could locate easily on my disc and added in config/environments/development.rb:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Sites\utils\GnuWin32\bin'
```

Comment: The right file for windows 10 is ImageMagick-7.0.7-28-Q16-x64-dll.exe . You then have to select "install legacy utilities (e.g. convert). I also selected ImageMagickObject OLE Control for VBscript, Visual Basic, and WSH)... Unless you have a win32 system, but check for the 7.0.7-28 version anyway

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like convert is already a default Windows command so you can't upload the picture properly.

1. Remove the `convert.exe` from your System32 files.
2. [Download](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) and install the **dynamic** ImageMagick (be sure to check the legacy support so the convert command gets supported)

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled ImageMagick and downloaded ImageMagick-7.0.7-28-Q16-x64-dll.exe for windows 10. Along with that I downloaded file.exe which is not present in windows 10 by default, unlike Linux. File.exe provides commands that allowed ImageMagick to configure properly and run